# sed not writing to file

Tags: bash, sed

I am having trouble using sed to substitute values and write to a new file. It writes to a new file, but fails to change any values. Here is my code:

```
cd/mydirectory  

echo "Enter file name:"
read file_input

file1= "$file_input"
file1= "$file1.b"

file2= "$file_input"
file2= "${file2}Ins.b"

sed "/\!cats!/s/\!cats!.*/cats!300!/g $file1>$file2
```

I simply want to substitute whatever text was after cats with the value 300. Whenever I run this script it doesn't overwrite the previous value with 300. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have those `!` in your file? Also, you should enclose `"$file1"` and `"$file2"` with double quotes on your `sed` line. Not sure it will fix your problem, but at least it should prevent your script form breaking if filenames contain spaces. (Speaking of double quotes, there's one missing at the end of your `sed "/…/s/…/…/` expression.)

Comment: And remove spaces after your `=` symbols on your `file1/2= "…"` lines.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
sed "/\!cats!/s/\!cats!.*/cats!300!/g $file1>$file2
```

to

```
sed "s/cats.*/cats300/g" $file1 > $file2
```

To replace text, you often have to use sed like `sed "s/foo/bar/g" file_in > file_out`, to change all occurrences of `foo` with `bar` in `file_in`, redirecting the output to `file_out`.

---

**Edit**

<strike>I noticed that you are redirecting the output to the same file - you can't do that</strike>.  You have 2 options:

- Redirect the results to another file, with a different filename.  e.g.:

  ```
  sed "s/cats.*/cats300/g" $file1 > $file2.tmp
  ```

  Note the `.tmp` after `$file2`
- Use the `-i` flag (if using GNU sed):

  ```
  sed -i "s/cats.*/cats300/g" $file1
  ```

  The `i` stands for *inline replacement*.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately the suggested changes did not work. I feel like both methods should be correct, but alas I can't seem to get them to work. Thanks again.

Comment: @OldMopMan I believe the problem is the output file then... you are using the same filename as the input file.  Remove the duplicated filenames definitions and try again using the above example.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, the changing of the file name worked, but why are they the same output file? You say that I am directing the output to the same file, but $file1 and $file2 shouldn't be the same. $file1 should be ${file1}.b and $file2 should be ${file2}Ins.b. Shouldn't the Ins make it a different file name?

Comment: @OldMopMan Yes, you are right regarding the file names - I just thought that those lines defining the file names are kind of misleading, as you define each of them twice.  When trying something new, I always try to do the minimum viable script possible, just to test if the functionality I'm looking for works.  If that works, then I try to build the other things around it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I really shouldn't have defined them twice. Anyway, it works when .tmp is hard coded after each variable in my sed statement, but does not work if I try to put the file extension (.tmp) in the variable like so:                                                                                                                                file2="${file2}.tmp"

Comment: Try it this way: `file2=${file2}.tmp`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I think I found the problem elsewhere. It was unclear because I did a poor job of posting my code. I actually have multiple sed statements writing to the same output file. I just didn't type them up because I thought I could get my point across with just one.  Apparently you can't have multiple sed statements writing to the same output file, so now I'm working on trying to find a way around this. Thanks again.

Comment: I have managedto reduce everythign to one sed statement using -e , but the script fails to work whenever my sed statement runs on to the next line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this modified version of your script should work:

```
echo "Enter file name:"
read file_input

file1="$file_input"     # No space after '='
file1="$file1.b"        # No space after '='

file2="$file_input"     # No space after '='
file2="${file2}Ins.b"   # No space after '='

sed 's/!cats!.*/!cats!300!/g' "$file1" > "$file2"
```

Note the single quotes around `sed` expression: with them, there's no need to escape the `!`s in your expression. Note also the double quotes around `"$file1"` and `"$file2"`: if one of those variables contain spaces, this will prevent your command from breaking.

Some further remarks:

- As pointed by jim, you may want to use the GNU sed `-i` option.
- Your regex will currently replace *everything* after `!cats!` in matching lines. If they were several occurences of `!cats!` on your line, only one will remain. If instead you just want to replace the value between two `!` delimiters, you may consider use following `sed` command instead:

  ```
  sed 's/!cats![^!]*/!cats!300/g'
  ```

Comment: sed -i "s/cats.*/cats300/g" $file1 this worked for me as well but can anyone explain why redirecting is not working though it too appear to work the same?

Comment: Do you mean why something like `sed 's/foo/bar/' $file1 > $file1` would not work? This is because the file is truncated before `sed` starts to read it, so you would process an empty file (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586461/70764) for example). Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Thanks I meant the same.  :)